# Installing python 3 for a specific environment

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, development-environment

I have `python 2.7.10` installed on my `mac`.

but I happen to need `Python 3` to use a `python wrapper` for a given `API`.

this is my folder structure:

```
apps/
    myapp/
         app.py
         gracenote/
                  pygn.py
```

where `pygn.py` is the wrapper which requires `Python 3`, while `app.py` requires `Python 2.7`

is there a way to run an isolated `Python` environment for the `wrapper`?

Comment: That seems like asking for trouble.  Can you fix your app to run under 3.x?  Installing 3.5 from python.org worked perfectly for me (on my mac), and I've had no issues with having both 2.7 and 3.5 installed at the same time.

Comment: @cco or maybe I should look for another API, given the fact that it serves a limited purpose...

Comment: Yep.   One or the other.  I've found that making my code work with either 2.7 or 3.5 is pretty easy (earlier 3.x were much harder), and 2020 (EOL for 2.x) is fast approaching, so I'm trying to move into the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to install both versions of python at the same time

```
$ which python3 # copy the output of this command
$ mkvirtualenv --python=/path/to/python3 ~/.virtualenvs/{your env name}
$ workon {your env name}
```

Comment: `virtualenv -p python3 env_name` is a simpler way of doing the same